# Toggling arrows on accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

First of all I have to say that I'm not all that familiar with jQuery, so bear with me here.
Now my problem: I have made an accordion for my website, and it has arrow images on the right side. The arrow is now toggling allright when I stick to opening and closing the same tab. But when I have one tab open and click another tab without closing the first one, the arrow keeps facing downward although its tab has closed. Can anyone help me out here?

This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".toggleAccordion").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-items').is(':visible') == false) {
            jQuery(".subcategories .subcategory-items").slideUp(600);
        }
        if(jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-arrow-closed').css('display') == 'none'){
            jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-arrow-closed').css('display', 'inline');
            jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-arrow-open').css("display", "none");
        }else{
            jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-arrow-closed').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-arrow-open').css("display", "inline");
        }
        jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-items').slideToggle(600);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add to the code that closes any open elements:

```
(...)
if(jQuery(this).closest('.accordion').find('.subcategory-items').is(':visible') == false) {
    jQuery(".subcategories .subcategory-items").slideUp(600);
    // Now remove open arrows.
    jQuery('.subcategory-arrow-closed').css('display', 'inline');
    jQuery('.subcategory-arrow-open').css('display', 'none');
}
(...)
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew my logic was failing somewhat there.